# Android Development/Debugging Best Practices

Tags: android

Does any one know what tools, techniques, skills are most practical on the Android platform to diagnose / fix bugs during development?

My issues are that my phone model does not seem to be supported by the Android Debug Bridge.  When I crank up the emulator, it runs about 10 times slower than my phone which results in a very inefficient, tedious, painful dev process.  When the app crashes, all that is shown is that an exception was thrown, there is no stacktrace presented (which I know is the standard).

If anyone can suggest any best practices to use within the limitations of the android platform it would be much appreciated.  I feel like I'm developing at tortoise speed here.

Thanks.

Byron

Comment: Which phone are you using?  What os?

Answer (score 2):

Logcat is your friend.  It will show a full stacktrace of any exceptions you received, and you can add judicious logging through out your app to help you diagnose problems.